# how to display posts in a single file like "article.php?id=" after link clicked in another file

Tags: php, mysql

i have a file where are displayed the post titles, i want that the post's content to be displayed in a single  php file like "article.php?id=".I just want some help how to do this using post's id.

Comment: i have't try nothing cause i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Then start reading up on PHP basics. This isn't a site for just giving out code, you have to put the effort in too.

Comment: Flukey, i was looking for somebody to show me the way, not giving the entire code

Answer (score 1):

On the page where you display the titles, you will use `<a href='article.php?id={$id}'>` to wrap the titles. Remember that the `$id` should be unique for each title. Clicking the anchor should take the user to article.php, on the page, get the id from the url and query your database for the article. e.g

```
//Get the id first
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

//Then query your database for the article
$result = mysql_query("SELECT article FROM article_tbl WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i tested it, and its all ok. I linked the titles to article.php with their own id, then I edited the query to match the id on the link and it is all ok. Thank you for understanding even that the question wasn't so clear ;)

Comment: Consider marking it as the correct answer if you may.